# Getting an error when useParams is invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's a Link component that I made:

```
const Restaurants = () => {
  const meatList = require('./Meat-Shops.json');

  return meatList.map((restaurant) => {
    return (
      <Link to={`/menu/${restaurant.store_name}`}>
        <div className="restaurant-container">
          <div className="image-container">
            <img src={restaurant.image} alt={restaurant.alt} />
          </div>
          <div className="info-container" >
            <h4>{restaurant.store_name}</h4>
            <h5>Pick-up</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>

    );
  })
}
```

When pressed, it will take me (or render) this component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'



const Menu = () => {
    console.log(useParams());
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Menu
```

What I am trying to do is to access `restaurant.store_name` (the URL parameter, variable at the end of the template string of the 'to' prop of the Link component) within the Menu component by using useParams(). But when I invoke useParams(), I get the following error:
[error_message_invalid_hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb2NM.png). What I am doing wrong? Also, here is the file that contains the  Router tags, if needed:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './Menu';
import Restaurants from './Restaurants';
import NavBar from "./NavBar"

const Pages = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <NavBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Restaurants />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/menu/:store_name" children={<Menu />} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Pages;
```

And here is the error message when I set:

```
const { menu } = useParams();
```

within the body of the 'menu' component (error message: [error_message_for_useParams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioJ30.jpg)).

You can also check out all of my code for the components (the Menu and Restaurants components) here on my GitHub: https://github.com/Toriong/quick_eat_carnivore_search_and_delivery

Comment: Did you also create an export for the restaurant component? Based on your example everything should work as expected.

Comment: const Menu = () => {
   const params = useParams();
    console.log(params);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    )
}

Comment: jean182, yes I exported the 'Restaurant' component. But it's still giving me an error even after I used your code Bogdan Prvyalov.

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the solution here. In this situation `useParams()` is looking at the `:store_name`, so you would destructure `store_name` from the params: `const { store_name } = useParams()` inside of your functional component.

Comment: That should work, but I am still getting an 'invalid hook call' error.

Comment: In the Router, change it from `children={<Menu />}` to `component={Menu}` and see if that works.